# Ready made browser library

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Are there any ready made iOS libraries that can acts as a built in browser in your apps? Basically I am looking for a UIWebView with back and forward buttons, reload, open in Safari and pro bonus for Save to Instapaper integration.

I have been trying to Google for this but can't find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself but [this](https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController) might be the kind of library I am looking for.